# Is there "Service Account User" concept in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working on Automation using **AzureDevOps** and wondering if there is a simple way to have a *service user account* i.e. account which creds never expires and can access **AzureDevOps** only via API.

I want to re-use this user credentials in my automation scripts but don't want to have user which can login to though UI.

Is there "Service Account User" concept in AzureDevOps.

P.S.

I know that pipelines provides ability to use OAuth token but what if I want to run automation outside the pipelines.

Comment: Where do you want to use Service Account User outside the pipeline?Is there a call to azure devops pipeline in your auto script?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT mainly I'm planning to call AzureDevOps rest API for my automation

Answer (score 6):

To perform automation outside pipelines, there's no need to create a service account. Instead, you can create an additional user and use a Personal Access Token (PAT) to automate. If you opt to use an OAuth token for pipeline automation, you can utilize the Service Project Collection Build Service Accounts, acting as a service user. This means you don't need a PAT, but automation must occur within pipelines. When creating a PAT, you can specify the necessary permissions.

Comment: Plz use punctuation marks. I read your answer a couple of times and still can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: It is preferable to have authentication of shared services independent of users. So, avoid using PATs for services that are not managed by that single user alone. Eg. if the employee leaves, account is disabled and then all automation using PATs of the user will stop. Same thing if the account is blocked for too many password attempts, broken into and disabled temporarily etc...

Comment: @adamt06 yes, in other case you can create TechUser dedicated for this, also not to block user. As user usage is throttled.

Answer (score 2):

It was not possible at the time this was asked, but now azure devops supports service principals and managed identities:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops